# Delete comments when migrating to other SE site

Tags: support, comment

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545107/how-to-order-values-on-a-dotplot-produced-via-qplot) post as off-topic and more suitable for SO. I had a two-part comment that listed four possible duplicate questions on SO. When the question was migrated, the first half of my comment didn't make the transition leaving the second half in limbo-land.

Was the first part of the comment deleted by a mod or is something not quite right with the transitions between sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what happened with your comments. Your first one is still visible, though. I checked myself some of the links you provided, before closing the question. I didn't delete your comments, and apparently they didn't migrate with the question.

I just noticed that Hadley suggested to use `reorder()` which was already proposed in the links you provided. Hence, your comments came very timely!

I'd like to add that I wouldn't have close it without clear indication of possible duplicates, because (a) a response was already provided, and (b) we welcome question on data visualization and ggplot2, although it's clearly better when they have something to do with information visualization and/or statistics.

Comment: Thanks chl for the response - we'll chalk it up to site gremlins this time. The bigger issue is how the community is going to deal with the overlap b/t SO and CV with regard to data vis questions. I know there has been some conversation on the topic, e.g. [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584/vote-on-policy-for-r-questions) and others. I suggested to move this question since it's content was very similar to the other question that was [moved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528709/adding-labels-inside) but I guess that came from meta, so more clear cut to move.

Comment: @Chase About your last point, yes: the question was posted on Meta which is not very appropriate. As it was barely interesting on its own--because I guess similar questions were already posted on SO (and there's a somewhat related solution on Hadley's website)--I just closed it.